# Conda:comando no encontrado

Tags: anaconda3

Por error he instalado anaconda3 en el diretorio `admin:///root/anaconda3`.
Intentando desinstalarlo inicio el proceso de desinstalación, desde el directorio base ejecutando `enri@enri-260-p100ns:~$ conda install anaconda clean`, me devuelve  `bash: conda: orden no encontrada`

Intento entrar en el directorio root desde una terminal haciendo  `enri@enri-260-p100ns:~$ cd admin:///root`, me devuelve `bash: cd: admin:///root: No existe el archivo o el directorio`
Si realizo otra instalación, esta vez en una carpeta en el directorio base, sin borrar esta instalación anterior, podría tener algún problema?. ¿Cómo eliminar la instalación equivocada?

¿Podría funcionar instalar anaconda3 en un entorno virtual nuevo?.Agradeceré su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

[conda:comando no encontrado](https://programmerclick.com/article/5875348206/)
Al usar anaconda para instalar python, a veces la ruta no se puede agregar a la ruta del sistema, debe agregar manualmente:
#Agregar el directorio bin de anaconda a PATH, dependiendo de la versión. Determine el nombre de anaconda, el mío es python3.6 para generar anaconda3

$ echo 'export PATH="~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"'>>~/.bashrc

#A continuación, actualice bashrc para que entre en vigencia inmediatamente sin apagar

$ source ~/.bashrc

Otra opción, para no tener que eliminar anaconda3 y volver a instalar. Se soluciona haciendo es.

```
source ~/anacona3/etc/profile.de/conda.sh
conda config --set auto_activate_base true
```

Finalmente, en mi caso, lo he conseguido haciendo.

```
cd /
cd root
cd anaconda3
rm -rf
```

Comment: A estas alturas, deberíás ya saber que puedes [edit] una pregunta o respuesta, cuantas veces haga falta, para detallar lo que quieres compartir. ¿Cuál es el punto de publicar tres respuestas que, además, parecen ser tres estados diferentes de tu exploración? Recuerda que no es un foro sino una colección de preguntas y respuestas. Si tienes una respuesta, publicas una respuesta; si la mejoras, la editas y le ayudas a los que vengan con el mismo problema. Ahora mismo sólo confundes a los demás.

Comment: Me pregunta, ¿Cuál es el punto de publicar tres respuestas que, además, parecen ser tres estados diferentes de tu exploración? . Cuando planteo una pregunta, es por que tengo un problema y solicito ayuda. Posteriormente, con el paso del tiempo, a media que voy aprendiendo, es posible que encuentre una respuesta a la pregunta formulaa en su día, que piense que podría ser bueno compartir como solución, para ayudar a otros usuario. Si esto no es correcto, dímelo y procederé a borrar esas respuestas.

Comment: Aunque noto eres un usuario que lleva tiempo en el sitio, no esta de mas sugerirte revisar nuevamente [answer], es importante realizar solo una respuesta que ayude a solucionar la problematica planteada en la pregunta, ahi puedes incluir varias opciones. Evita agregar varias respuestas por favor.

Comment: Revisa el enlace que te comparten, y puedes plasmar el desarrollo de tu propia solución en una única respuesta. Así será evidente para todos qué es lo que compartes y qué iba primero, qué va después y qué es lo que te funciona. :) Lamento no ser yo mismo de ayuda; gracias por compartir tu avance hacia la solución